# Using Phone Gap To Find iOS Device Speed?

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Is there a plug in for phone gap that exposes the velocity of the iOS device?

Comment: to tell how fast the device is moving

Comment: Like knowing the clock speed? Or how much distance the phone is covering?

Comment: pretty much the velocity. So if the person\device is walking, running, driving, or flying